# Recursive use of png optimization

Tags: image, optimization, png

I have been accustomed to use Tinypng to optimize my png files, and today I discovered that by repeating the optimization on the newly optimized file, further savings in size can be achieved. In fact by repeating this many times until there was no longer any reduction, I achieved savings of about 30-50% of the original optimized file without any noticeable change in the image.

Has anyone else noticed/tried this? Can someone explain why this occurs?

Comment: Can you run such a successively compressed PNG through `pngcheck -vv` and post the differences between each iterarion?

Answer (score 0):

> TinyPNG uses smart lossy compression techniques to reduce the file size of your PNG files.

This means it is not lossless. Even if you can't see any difference, every time you use TinyPNG to optimize png, the image quality is reduced a little bit.

To compare two images, try http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php